# A dynamically changeable wpf animation

Tags: simulation

I'm making a zero-player c# wpf football simulation and I have the field laid out and everything, just no players or ball doing anything at the moment. 
How could I make the players move, for a start? And for seconds, colliding with the ball imparts the player's velocity on it somehow?
C# Express 2010, all help appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this to get you started:
[Beginner's WPF Animation Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFAnimation.aspx)

That should get you to a point where you're ready to ask more specific questions.